# Какой паттерн стоит использовать для конфигурации модуля web-приложения?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Опять поймал себя на том, что изобретаю паттерн. 
Есть несколько однотипных сущностей - сервисов web приложения. У сервисов общий интерфейс и родитель. Хочется прийти к единообразию работы с конфигами модулей. 
Все конфиги представляют собой php файл примерно такого содержания: `return ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2', etc....]`. 
Я решил, что каждый сервис будет содержать список дефолтных значений конфига, а конфиг не будет являться обязательным. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что нужно писать геттеры и сеттеры, но в самом ли сервисе или создавать сущность конфига сервиса? Ответом буду считать название паттерна с краткими комментариями по его использованию.

Comment: А с чего вы вообще решили, что вам нужен именно паттерн? Простого разделения обязанностей по классам уже недостаточно? Почему?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Виды разделения обязанностей по классам и способы их реализации и есть паттерны. Советую ознакомится.

Comment: Спасибо, я в курсе, что такое паттерны. Тот факт, что паттерны _необходимы_ далеко не всегда становится после года-двух объектного проектирования. Советую потратить ближайший год с пользой ;)

Comment: По теме вопроса - хотите прям паттерн - используйте DI контейнер. Почему это так - мне объяснять лень. Может кто-то, кто знает что такое паттерны придет и напишет развернутый ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Перед тем, как написать класс, я и задал этот вопрос. Я не использую паттерны везде, где они нужны или нет. https://github.com/ilyaplot/php-helpers/blob/master/Config.php